# C++ Win32 API Load a driver to the kernel space

Tags: c++, windows, kernel

Is there a Win32/native API function for loading and executing a kernelmode program in the kernelspace? (.sys, .exe)

Comment: You can load and start a device driver with CreateService(), service type SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, start type SERVICE_DEMAND_START.

Answer (score 4):

First you get a handle to the service manager with [OpenSCManager()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-openscmanagera).

Then you call [CreateService()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-createservicea) using SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER & SERVICE_DEMAND_START, this will load the driver.

Here is a good example of a function which does it all for you with error checking:

```cpp
BOOL LoadNTDriver(WCHAR* lpszDriverName, WCHAR* lpszDriverPath)
{
    WCHAR szDriverImagePath[256];

    GetFullPathName(lpszDriverPath, 256, szDriverImagePath, NULL);
    BOOL bRet = FALSE;

    SC_HANDLE hServiceMgr = NULL;
    SC_HANDLE hServiceDDK = NULL;

    hServiceMgr = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

    if (hServiceMgr == NULL)
    {

        printf("OpenSCManager() Faild %d ! \n", GetLastError());
        bRet = FALSE;
        goto BeforeExit;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OpenSCManager() ok ! \n");
    }

    hServiceDDK = CreateService(hServiceMgr,
        lpszDriverName, 
        lpszDriverName,
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,
        SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER,
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
        SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE,
        szDriverImagePath,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    DWORD dwRtn;

    if (hServiceDDK == NULL)
    {
        dwRtn = GetLastError();
        if (dwRtn != ERROR_IO_PENDING && dwRtn != ERROR_SERVICE_EXISTS)
        {
            printf("CrateService() Faild %d ! \n", dwRtn);
            bRet = FALSE;
            goto BeforeExit;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("CrateService() Faild Service is ERROR_IO_PENDING or ERROR_SERVICE_EXISTS! \n");
        }

        hServiceDDK = OpenService(hServiceMgr, lpszDriverName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
        if (hServiceDDK == NULL)
        {
            dwRtn = GetLastError();
            printf("OpenService() Faild %d ! \n", dwRtn);
            bRet = FALSE;
            goto BeforeExit;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("OpenService() ok ! \n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("CrateService() ok ! \n");
    }

    bRet = StartService(hServiceDDK, NULL, NULL);
    if (!bRet)
    {
        DWORD dwRtn = GetLastError();
        if (dwRtn != ERROR_IO_PENDING && dwRtn != ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING)
        {
            printf("StartService() Faild %d ! \n", dwRtn);
            bRet = FALSE;
            goto BeforeExit;
        }
        else
        {
            if (dwRtn == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
            {
                printf("StartService() Faild ERROR_IO_PENDING ! \n");
                bRet = FALSE;
                goto BeforeExit;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("StartService() Faild ERROR_SERVICE_ALREADY_RUNNING ! \n");
                bRet = TRUE;
                goto BeforeExit;
            }
        }
    }
    bRet = TRUE;

BeforeExit:
    if (hServiceDDK)
    {
        CloseServiceHandle(hServiceDDK);
    }
    if (hServiceMgr)
    {
        CloseServiceHandle(hServiceMgr);
    }
    return bRet;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/roycncn/PUBG-wall-hacking-user-mode/blob/master/MapESP/LoadDriver.hpp

Answer (score -3):

As far as I'm aware, no. You can't do that that way (which would be quite a massive security issue). You'll have to properly register the driver and get Windows to load it.

The latter can be done using the [DIFxAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544834(v=vs.85).aspx), which you should read up on MSDN, since it's far too complex to put it in an simple answer here.

The core function you should be looking for is [`DriverPackageInstall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544813(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I found this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31905/A-C-class-wrapper-to-load-unload-device-drivers

Comment: You can use the CreateService() API, much simpler than the device management API.  There's no security issue; you need admin privilege, of course, and driver signing requirements (if enabled) still apply, just as if you were installing an ordinary driver in the usual way.